# how to read firebase database download size with firebase CLI

Tags: android, command-line-interface

My question is simple, how do I see the amount of data downloaded in a Child in Firebase Realtime Database in CLI. How can I do that .

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. In that : "firebase database:profile -P project_id".